# How can I disable Slick JS library of elementor (plugin)?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

How can I disable Slick JS library of elementor, it happens that I have another plugin that needs to use this library, but that generates a css conflict. The other plugin is Directories Pro. I hope you can help me and there is a simple way to disable this library in elementor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_dequeue_script();` function to derefister the js file. Check the function referance [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script).

Comment: I have added the code to  /wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php But it still doesn't work.